# spacyr installation on R: /usr/local/bin/python is not a python executable

Tags: r, installation, spacy

I used this [instruction](https://github.com/kbenoit/spacyr) to install spacyr on RStudio (mac os)

I have both python 2 and 3 so I run

```
library(spacyr)
spacy_initialize(python_executable = "/usr/local/bin/python")
```

It returns an error:

```
Error in check_spacy_model(python_executable, model) : 
/usr/local/bin/python is not a python executable
```

Any advice on how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have spaCy installed in multiple pythons? If not, you don't have to specify `python_executable` option. By just running `spacy_initialize()` without specifying the option, the function should be able to find the python with spaCy.

Comment: Hi, spacy_initialize() without the option returns the same error: Finding a python executable with spacy installed...
Error in spacy_initialize() : 
  spaCy or language model en is not installed in any of python executables.
the terminal shows installation successful though

Comment: Could you show the output of `which -a python` and `which -a python3` from Terminal?

Comment: Could you also test `spacy_initialize(python_executable = "/usr/local/bin/python3")`?

Comment: @amatsuo_net thanks for reply. for executable=python3 this is the error 
 spaCy or language model en is not installed in /usr/local/bin/python3. i've installed en model, but maybe now python3?

Comment: for which -a python it returns Users/santoku/anaconda/bin/python
for which -a python3 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: Do you know to which python you installed `spaCy` and a language model? You can check by `python -c  "import spacy; spacy.load('en'); print('OK')"` and `python3 -c  "import spacy; spacy.load('en'); print('OK')"`. (if you use a language model other than English, replace `en` something appropriately. Either one should return "OK".

Comment: By the way, based on your stackoverflow post, we've updated the package. You can try it out with `devtools::install_github("kbenoit/spacyr")`. I'm hoping that this will find the python by jsut entering `spacy_initialize()` in your environment.

Comment: it works now! i just have to replace usr/local/bin to the actual path, perhaps I didn't install python in the standard location. thanks for the step-by-step instruction

Comment: good to know that it is working now. thank you for using `spacyr`!

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time figuring out this issue for myself. For me the problem was I had installed spacy using conda rather than pip so it was unable to setup symlink.

1. uninstall spacyr
2. uninstall spacy from python(if you have installed using conda)
3. Install spacy with pip only
4. Install the latest version of spacyr from github.